# Unable to bring up the Keycloak instance in local using Bitnami image

Tags: keycloak, bitnami

Unable to bring up keycloak instance in local using below command

```
docker run --name keycloak-local bitnami/keycloak:20.0.5-debian-11-r1
```

Please find the error details

```
keycloak 09:26:46.21
keycloak 09:26:46.22 Welcome to the Bitnami keycloak container
keycloak 09:26:46.22 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
keycloak 09:26:46.22 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
keycloak 09:26:46.22
keycloak 09:26:46.22 INFO  ==> ** Starting keycloak setup **
keycloak 09:26:46.23 INFO  ==> Validating settings in KEYCLOAK_* env vars...
keycloak 09:26:46.26 INFO  ==> Trying to connect to PostgreSQL server postgresql...
cannot resolve host "postgresql": lookup postgresql on 192.168.65.7:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:46446->192.168.65.7:53: i/o time
```

Answer (score 4):

The reasons is `bitnami/keycloak` looking for default database(PostgreSQL) connection.

So you needs to run both docker images(`keycloak` and `postgresql`) by `docker compose` from [here](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/blob/main/bitnami/keycloak/docker-compose.yml)

```
version: '2'
services:
  postgresql:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:11
    environment:
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=bn_keycloak
      - POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=bitnami_keycloak
    volumes:
      - 'postgresql_data:/bitnami/postgresql'

  keycloak:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/keycloak:20
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

volumes:
  postgresql_data:
    driver: local
```

By launching `docker-compose` v2.0 at the same directory of `docker-compose.yml` file.

I changed port forwarding port from `80` to `8080` in line 18 of `docker-compose.yml`

If you want to stick with specific Key cloak version, replace line 14

```
image: bitnami/keycloak:20.0.5-debian-11-r1
```

```
docker compose up
```

Default Admin Credential in [here](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/keycloak) documentation

Acess the Keycloak by Browser

```
localhost:8080
```

And Login with default credential.

```
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_USER: Administrator default user. Default: user.
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: Administrator default password. Default: bitnami.
```

You can see Keycloak master page fter success to login as master admin.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for giving a qucik solution and it's working as expected. Do we have any sample docker file to create an keycloak image using source code in local?

Comment: You are welcome, Bitnami provides Dockerfile in [here](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/blob/main/bitnami/keycloak/20/debian-11/Dockerfile). Can you vote to me?

Comment: Bitnami moved Dockerfile in [here](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/blob/main/bitnami/keycloak/22/debian-11/Dockerfile)